# Executing a PHP Script with Arduino and Ethernet Shield

Tags: get, ethernet, arduino-uno

Im working on a project with an Arduino and Ethernet Shield.

I would like to execute a php script (residing on my server) in the loop.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// MAC address from Ethernet shield sticker under board
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,77); // IP address, may need to change depending on network
EthernetServer server(80);  // create a server at port 80

String HTTP_req;            // stores the HTTP request

void setup()
{
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);  // initialize Ethernet device
    server.begin();           // start to listen for clients
    Serial.begin(9600);       // for diagnostics
}

void loop()
{
    EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client

    if (client) {  // got client?
        boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
        while (client.connected()) {
            if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
                char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
                HTTP_req += c;  // save the HTTP request 1 char at a time
                Serial.print("connected");
                client.println("GET http://domain.com/arduino/scripts/script_motion_detection_driveway.php HTTP/1.0");
                client.println();
            } // end if (client.available())
        } // end while (client.connected())
        delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
        client.stop(); // close the connection
    } // end if (client)
}
```

When I run the code and load the page, instead of executing the script it just prints the line:

```
GET http://domain.com/arduino/scripts/script_motion_detection_driveway.php HTTP/1.0
```

over and over again...

The reason its in the loop as opposed to setup is because eventually the GET request will be placed inside an if statement to test a condition.

What do I need to change to execute the script?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this example: http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebClient

You want to execute a GET request without telling the client to connect to the server at the port 80.

```
if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
```

Then you make your http request

```
// Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
```

Then you try to read the request

```
if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }
```

By putting these parts together in a better way than your script above, you will successfully get the output of your php script.